# Android: how to clear completely FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my Activity A, I add some fragments (standard case). I've checked, on my Android phone settings, "Don't keep Activities" to simulate worst application behavior.

So, when this Activity A restart, I do that in onCreate() method, to clean all my previous fragments added :

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> al = fm.getFragments();
    if (al != null) {
        for (Fragment frag : al) {
            if (frag != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately I can see in the logs, these kind of informations:

```
Successful to getNewsFeedInteractionsList() #2
Successful to getNewsFeedInteractionsList() #2
Successful to getNewsFeedUserList() #Suivis
Successful to getNewsFeedUserList() #Populaire
Successful to getNewsFeedUserList() #Populaire
Successful to getNewsFeedUserList() #Suivis
```

You can see, all these fragments are appears twice ...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While adding fragments you can set tags. Based on those tags handle duplicate addition in `onCreate`. 
As well you use  `savedBundle` instance for null check